# Regex match first character once, followed by repetitive matching until end

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match characters that shouldn't be allowed in a username string to then be replaced.

Anything outside this range should match first character `[a-zA-Z]` <-- restricting the first character is causing problems and I don't know how to fix it

And then match everything else outside this range `[0-9a-zA-Z_.]` <---- repeat until the end of the string

Matches:

- /////hey///  <-- first match `/////`, second match `///`
- [][123Bc_.// <-- first match `[][`, second match `//`
- (/abc        <-- should match `(/`
- a2__./)      <-- should match `/)`

Non Matches:

- a_____
- b__...

Current regex

```js
/^([^a-zA-Z])([^\w.])*/
```

```js
const regex = /^([^a-zA-Z])([^0-9a-zA-Z_.])*/;
'(/abc'.replace(regex, '') // => return expected abc
'/////hey///'.replace(regex, '') // => return expected "hey"
```

Comment: Go to https://regex101.com/ and try out some ideas. You may succeed, but even if you don't, you will learn a lot about regexes, and you can come back here and report what you tried.

Comment: I'm sure there's a dupetarget for this, so I'll just comment: Your description matches the regex `/^[a-z][a-z0-9]+$/i`. But based on your comments on the matches you've shown, it's not clear to me what you're really doing.

Comment: @MichaelGeary - They did try to do it, and linked to that very site.

Comment: *"should match everything apart from hey"* What does that mean? I thought you were trying to validate a username.

Comment: *"Regex101 attempt"* Your attempt should be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put your attempted regex **in** the question.

Comment: Like this? `^\W+([\w.]+)\W+$` https://regex101.com/r/v8iyHp/1 or `^[^\w.]+([\w.]+)[^\w.]+$`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder So I want the first character to be a letter from `[a-zA-Z]` meaning match everything else, and the rest `[0-9a-zA-Z_.]` meaning (letters.underscores, dots), so I'm trying to replace every character not included in the sets.

Comment: btw, `[0-9a-zA-Z_.]` can be rewritten as `[\w.]` since \w contans `0-9a-zA-Z_`

Comment: @programmer - *"So I want the first character to be a letter from [a-zA-Z] meaning match everything else"* Which is it? A letter from `[a-zA-Z]` or "everything else"? It can't be both.

Comment: _“so I'm trying to replace every character not included in the sets”_ - not a good idea to begin with, IMHO. Chances are that at some point you will reduce a combination of characters to some offensive word or something similar, without the user actually having intended for that to happen in the first place. _Notify_ the user about the non-allowed characters and ask them to correct their input accordingly, but don’t do it automatically for them.

Comment: @CBroe I'm trying to achieve a similar behavior to instagram, if a wrong character is inserted it gets replaced and  a shake animation is initiated

Comment: You can not do it this way, with negated character classes and the pattern anchored at the start. For example for your `a2__./)`, this of course won’t match - because the first character is _not_ in the disallowed range, so the whole expression doesn’t match. The easiest way to achieve this, would probably be to ensure the requirements for the first character, and those for the rest, in two separate steps.

Comment: @CBroe how do I skip the first character in the second regex? Or should i just split the string?

Comment: Your allowed characters for the first position are a subset, of what you want to allow for “the rest” - so do that second part first, replace everything that does not match `[0-9a-zA-Z_.]` with an empty string, without anchoring the pattern at the beginning or end. And then, in the _result_ of that operation, replace any characters not matching `[a-zA-Z]` from the beginning. (So _that_ pattern gets anchored at the beginning, and you want to use `+` as quantifier - because when you remove the first invalid character, the next one becomes the new first, and might still be invalid.)

Comment: @CBroe I managed to get it sorted as you suggested thank you, you can put this in the answer, maybe someone someday finds it helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/^([^a-zA-Z])([^\w.])*/
```

You can not do it this way, with negated character classes and the pattern anchored at the start. For example for your `va2__./)`, this of course won’t match - because the first character is not in the disallowed range, so the whole expression doesn’t match.

Your allowed characters for the first position are a subset, of what you want to allow for “the rest” - so do that second part first, replace everything that does not match `[0-9a-zA-Z_.]` with an empty string, without anchoring the pattern at the beginning or end.
And then, in the result of that operation, replace any characters not matching `[a-zA-Z]` from the start. (So that second pattern *does* get anchored at the beginning, and you’ll want to use `+` as quantifier - because when you remove the first invalid character, the next one becomes the new first, and that one might still be invalid.)